# validate particular form controls on respective action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

In my MVC web application, I have two `Html.BeginForm()` with the same controller and different action on single view. When I click the button of first `Html.BeginForm()`, It shows validation message for both the form where as I want it just for single form. Look at my code below.

```
  //First Html.BeginForm()
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddFirst", "Student", FormMethod.Post, new  { id = "form1", role = "form"  }))
{
 <tr>
<td>
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.MobileNo)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MobileNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "TextMobile", @class = "form-control", @maxlength = "10", @placeholder = "Mobile No" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MobileNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</td>
<td>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="First Button" class="btn btn-default" />
</td>
 </tr>
  }

   //Second Html.BeginForm()
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddSecond", "Student", FormMethod.Post, new  {     id = "form2", role = "form"  }))
 {
   <tr>
  <td>
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.MobileNo)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MobileNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "TextMobile2", @class = "form-control", @maxlength = "10", @placeholder = "Mobile No" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MobileNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</td>
<td>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Second Button" class="btn btn-default" />
 </td>
 </tr>
  }
```

In above case, when I Click on First button It shows validation message for both the mobile number, But I want to show validation message for one mobile number(Same for Second Button). How to validate only single text box of particular form? I have taken different action for this purpose. In my controller, I have two actions.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddFirst(string submit, User u)
    {
        agree = new Agree(u);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
    //Some logic
            return View("ThisView", agree);
        }
        else
        {
            return View("ThisView", agree);
        }

    }


[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddSecond(string submit, User u)
    {
        agree = new Agree(u);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
    //Some logic
            return View("ThisView", agree);
        }
        else
        {
            return View("ThisView", agree);
        }

        }
```

And In my model, I have

```
    [DisplayName("Mobile Number")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please Enter Mobile Number")]
    public string MobileNo { get; set; }
```

Comment: your code is worked  for me... check it again...

Comment: It working but it showing validation for both the textbox when I click on single button of any form, I wan only one validation for particular textbox to be display. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Because you are creating multiple `ValidationMessageFor()` for the same properties. What is the point of this - you can only submit one form at a time - your implementation makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating three model class

```
public class AddFirstMobileViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("Mobile Number")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please Enter Mobile Number")]
    public string MobileNo { get; set; }
}

public class AddSecondMobileViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("Mobile Number")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please Enter Mobile Number")]
    public string MobileNo { get; set; }
}

public class MobileViewModel
{
    public AddFirstMobile FirstMobileNumber{get;set;}

    public AddSecondMobile SecondMobileNumber{get;set;}
}
```

In the view update the code like

```
@model AppName.Models.MobileViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddFirst", "Student", FormMethod.Post, new  { id = "form1", role = "form"  }))
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstMobileNumber.MobileNo)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstMobileNumber.MobileNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "TextMobile", @class = "form-control", @maxlength = "10", @placeholder = "Mobile No" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstMobileNumber.MobileNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="First Button" class="btn btn-default" />
        </td>
    </tr>
  }

//Second Html.BeginForm()
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddSecond", "Student", FormMethod.Post, new  {     id = "form2", role = "form"  }))
 {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SecondMobileNumber.MobileNo)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SecondMobileNumber.MobileNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "TextMobile2", @class = "form-control", @maxlength = "10", @placeholder = "Mobile No" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SecondMobileNumber.MobileNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Second Button" class="btn btn-default" />
        </td>
    </tr>
  }
```

after this on clicking submit button of one form shows validation for thr respective form and save the data to db
Hope this helps.

Comment: Can I take MobileNo in two different models, Because I am using Database first Entity framework approach. So in database I should have only one `MobileNo` field. I there anotrher approach to achieve this?

Comment: Ok Anand , I will try this now.

Comment: It doesn't showing Mobile number validation for both the textbox.

Comment: Do I need to create another class? will it affect for database model?

Comment: then your saving the data from two forms in one table

Comment: Yes, I have to save value from this two forms to single table according to condition

Comment: i have changed the model. save the mobile to your table